# Add a new column to a 2d array using mapped values from another 2d array, otherwise use default value of zero

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, default-value

I need to merge the data from two 2d arrays based on shared ID column values. While transferring NUM values from the second array to the first array, if there is no corresponding row, default the NUM value to 0.

```
$array1 = [
    ['ID' => 1],
    ['ID' => 2],
    ['ID' => 3],
    ['ID' => 4],
    ['ID' => 5],
];

$array2 = [
    ['ID' => 2, 'NUM' => 200],
    ['ID' => 4, 'NUM' => 400],
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ['ID' => 1, 'NUM' => 0],
    ['ID' => 2, 'NUM' => 200],
    ['ID' => 3, 'NUM' => 0],
    ['ID' => 4, 'NUM' => 400],
    ['ID' => 5, 'NUM' => 0],
]
```

I tried `array_diff()` and `array_intersect()`, but could not find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array1 and add the value of array2 for the current key or 0 if the key is not set in array2.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $array2) {
    $array1[$key] = $array2[$key];
  } else {
    $array1[$key] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid inefficient iterated searches of the second array, populate an associative lookup/map to permit instant value access.  If an ID is not found in the lookup, default to new element to 0.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/5MRHC)

```
$array1 = [
    ['ID' => 1],
    ['ID' => 2],
    ['ID' => 3],
    ['ID' => 4],
    ['ID' => 5],
];
$array2 = [
    ['ID' => 2, 'NUM' => 200],
    ['ID' => 4, 'NUM' => 400],
];

$lookup = array_column($array2, null, 'ID');
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row + ($lookup[$row['ID']] ?? ['NUM' => 0]),
        $array1
    )
);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to mutate the first array, references can be used with two loops. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OKmYh))

```
foreach ($array1 as ['ID' => $id, 'NUM' => &$ref[$id]]) {
    $ref[$id] = 0;
}
foreach ($array2 as ['ID' => $id, 'NUM' => $ref[$id]]);
var_export($array1);
```